# I want to create a program that asks for input and find it in a list, so what may I have done wrong here

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_list=[1,5,8,3]
y= input('Enter your number: ')
a= int(y)
if a in my_list
   print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

And in gives me:
File "", line 4
    if a in my_list
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of your if - it should be: `if a in my_list:` You might also want to make sure your indentation is consistent - those `print`s shouldn't be at different positions

Comment: Thanks buddy. it worked, but do i always need to put the `:`  @JonClements

Comment: Yes... if/for/while loops etc... all require a `:` at the end of the line and then the following block that's relevant to be indented... it's the syntax that Python uses...